# Failed to add CodeQL library from a differnet folder: "Could not resolve module <xxx>"

Tags: c++, codeql, semmle-ql

I have the following folder structure:

```
└── MyProj
    ├── Dangerous_Memcopy
    │   ├── Config.qll
    │   └── ...
    ├── MemMangementLibraries
    │   ├── FFmpegMemory
    │   └── ...
```

This is the beginning of `Config.qll`:

```
import cpp
import Utils
// Change here the memory library if wrappers exists in project
import MemMangementLibraries.FFmpegMemory
import semmle.code.cpp.dataflow.TaintTracking



class MyConfig extends TaintTracking::Configuration{
    MyConfig() {this = "MyConfig"}

    override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node node){
        exists(
            CallAllocationExpr alloc_foo | 
            (
                node.asExpr() = alloc_foo
                and not alloc_foo.getFile().toString().matches("%mem.c%")
            )
        )
    }

...
```

I have an error on the four line: `import MemMangementLibraries.FFmpegMemory`:

> Could not resolve module MemMangementLibraries.FFmpegMemory

I don't understand why. I gave the import with the name of the folder following the name of the library:

```
import MemMangementLibraries.FFmpegMemory
```

Any idea what can be the problem?
If I move the library `FFmpegMemory.qll` to be under the folder `Dangerous_Memcopy` and change the fourth line in `Config.qll` to `import FFmpegMemory`, it will accept it.

It seems that it doesn't recognize the folder `MemMangementLibraries` that is used in the import.

Answer (score 0):

Imports in QL are resolved relative to the "QL pack root", which is the nearest enclosing directory containing a [`qlpack.yml`](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-cli/about-ql-packs/#ql-pack-structure) file. (They are also resolved relatively to the file containing the `import` statement, which is why this works if you move the library next to the importing file.)

In this case, could it be that your `MyProj` directory does not contain a `qlpack.yml`? If it is itself in a QL pack (that is, its parent contains a `qlpack.yml`), then you should be able to import it as `MyProj. MemMangementLibraries.FFmpegMemory`. Alternatively, you could add a minimal `qlpack.yml` in it to make imports work.